# Is there a way for preprocessor macros to insert arguments without me putting whitespace on either side of it?

Tags: macros, preprocessor

To make a somewhat long story short, I'm trying to do this:

```
#define MY_MACRO(x) id myObjectx;
```

to create `myObject1` and `myObject2` and so on. I have a lot of these, and the real situation is a little more complicated than just declaring the object and that's it, I need it to repeat a few different things with that number, and copy-paste is getting ugly.

Note: I understand that with the information I've given you you'll be tempted to suggest I just use an array, so I'll explain - I need a bunch of separate KVO properties, and they can't all go in a to-many because the amount of change notifications would get out of hand.

Comment: Nope, first I'd heard of it @bmargulies, found an explanation here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation - bmargulies feel free if you want to type that in as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bmargulies said, you can use `##` in the macro:

```
#define MY_MACRO(x) id myObject##x;
```

bmargulies, why don't you add your comment as an answer...?

Comment: I was too lazy to confirm for sure that it did the job. You're welcome to the rep.